# How many subgroups of order $p^2$ are in $\mathbb{Zp \times Zp \times Zp}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have two ideas to develop this problem, the first to use the Euler function, since Zp is cyclic. And the other is to use the canonical projection.
I appreciate your ideas

Comment: Your group is a $\;p\,-$ elementary abelian group and thus a linear space over the field $\;\Bbb F_p\cong\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z\;$ . To count subgroups here is exactly the same as to count subspaces there...

Comment: These kind of questions are never well defined... do you consider $\mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{Z}_p\times \{0\}$ the same as $\{0\}\times \mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{Z}_p$? Anyway by the structure of finite abelian groups every subgroup of order $p^2$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{Z}_p$ or is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ but the latter can't be a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_p\times\mathbb{Z}_p\times\mathbb{Z}_p$

Comment: @Yanko I think the question is perfectly well defined, and your examples are two very different subgroups, just as $\;\{(1),(12)\}\;,\;\;\{(1),(13)\}\;$ are two completely different subgroups of $\;S_3\;$ , no matter they have the same order.

Comment: @DonAntonio It's not just that they have the same order; it's that they're isomorphic. It seems likely that OP wants all subgroups, not just 'all subgroups up to isomorphism' but I agree that that's not clear from the question.

Comment: @DonAntonio Yea I see your point. Somehow, in my opinion, it feels natural to identify isomorphic subgroups...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I really don't see it that way, otherwise what'd you answer to the question "How many subspaces are there in $\;\Bbb R^2\;$? Because up to dimension, and isomorphism, there are only three. Different groups are different groups, otherwise this question is almost completely trivial: there are four different subgroups up to isomorphism. Very unsatisfactory, imo.

Comment: @Yanko I really don't see it that way at all...nor does Galois theory, say.  Anyway, that'd make this question almost trivial.

Comment: The question is not trivial for me.

Comment: Following the suggestion of Tomasz I have found this text : https://arxiv.org/abs/1006.2193. Maybe this can help you too, Gabriela

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Your group is a three-dimensional vector space over the $p$-element field. A subgroup of a vector space over such a field is always a vector subspace.

Comment: There is no other way to do it?

Comment: It's such an elementary problem that there are probably dozens of ways to do it. But I think this is the easiest.